# Module to manage HTTP errors

Tags: perl, http, module

I'm writing a Perl module `Result` to manage HTTP errors.

I am a little lost to generate the function managing all this.

#### Result.pm

```
package Result;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Log::Log4perl;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my %params = @_;

    my $self = {
        code      => $params{'code'},
        value     => $params{'value'}
    };

    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub generateError
{
    my $self = shift;
    my %params = @_;

    if($self->{'code'} == 200)
    {
        return "Your request was well executed !";
    }
    elsif($self->{'code'} == 400)
    {
        return "There is an error in your request! Please verify it!";
    }
    elsif($self->{'code'} == 404)
    {
        return "We did not find for what you ask !"
    }
    elsif($self->{'code'} == 500)
    {
        return "Internal error of the server, please re-try later !";
    }
    elsif($self->{'code'} == 504)
    {
        return "Your request has set of time to be executed, please retry !";
    }
}

1;
```

#### App.pm

```
sub template
{
    my $self = shift;

    my $query   = $self->query;
    my $id = $query->param('id');

    my $session = $self->param('session');
    my $profile = $session->param('profile');

    my $Project = Project->newFromId($id);
    if(!$Project or $Project eq 'NOT_FOUND')
    {
        return $self->redirect('?rm=notfound');
    }

    if(!$profile->{'uid'} or $Project->{'userId'} != $profile->{'uid'})
    {
        return $self->redirect('?rm=notfound');
    }

    my $mailContent = from_json($Project->{'mail'});

    my $templateContent = formatTemplate($Project->{'template'});

    my $infos = [
        {
            'ID'        => $id,
            'TEMPLATE'  => $templateContent,
            'MAILSUBJECT'   => $mailContent->{'subject'},
            'MAILBODY'  => $mailContent->{'body'}
        }
    ];

    if($mailContent->{'type'} eq 'text')
    {
        $infos->[0]{'MAILTEXT'} = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $infos->[0]{'MAILHTML'} = 1;
    }

    return $self->processtmpl('template.tmpl', $infos); 
}
1;
```

Comment: You need to show the code that uses your module and describe in detail how it isn't doing what you want.

Comment: Exactly, before verifying all of that, I would like to know if the syntax of the function generateError() is correct or not

Comment: Why ask us? The Perl compiler is much more reliable. What does `perl -c Result.pm` tell you?

Comment: as @Borodin mentioned, you can check the syntax of your module using `perl -c Result.pm` but I am a little confused by the question, what do you mean by _"I am a little lost to generate the function managing all this"_? Do you want to know how you will need to use the module from a main script?

Comment: There is a bug in that, if all of the `if`/`elsif` tests fail, no `return` statement is executed and it is far from obvious what value will actually be returned.

Comment: Are you aware of the `HTTP::Response` module?

Comment: Oh, no I'm not :/

Comment: When I launch perl -c Result.pm, it returns me this : "Result.pm syntax OK" Furthermore, I edited my subject by adding a function on which I am going to have to modify to take into account functions of Result.pm

Comment: @Maestro Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to look into [testing your module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Tutorial) to make sure it does what it's supposed to do. But Ii's not clear to me how App and Result relate. There do not appear to be any HTTP requests in App for Result to generate an error message from.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern ! :) Actually, I am trying to relate App.pm and Result.pm to generate http error, but I don't know how to do it :/

Comment: I am curious what the overall goal of your project is. Are you writing your own web framework? Now of course we've all tried that (though we don't all admit to it), but to be honest, that might not be a good exercise early on in your career. It might be smarter to master one or more of the existing web frameworks first, and if you are really interested in how they work, why not start contributing to one? 1/2

Comment: ... The [Dancer2](https://p3rl.org/Dancer2) project is always looking for [new contributors](https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/issues?q=is:open+is:issue+label:%22Beginner+Suitable%22), and they have some really nice people on their team. 2/2

Comment: I am currently working on a website allowing users to create Surveys, campaigns, datasets from csv file to generate graphics via dashboards.

Comment: @Maestro There's no HTTP calls in App.pm, so there's no obvious relation. We'd need to know why you think you need Result.pm. And there's not enough information about your surrounding code, like what is handling `$self->query`? Is it [CGI::Application](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Application)? As others have mentioned, you probably shouldn't be doing such low level error handling. A better web framework such as [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2) and their plugins can handle that.